# Pipes and cisterns question .

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Question

Two pipes P and Q can fill a cistern in 12 min. and 15 min. respectively but a third pipe ‘R’ can empty the full tank in 6 min.  P and Q are kept open for 5 min in the beginning and then ‘R’ is also opened.  In what time will the cistern be empty ?

My answer :-

Let t be the total time P and Q are open.
Now, Total inflow = Total outflow

((1/12) + (1/15))*t = (1/6)(t-5)

On solving I am getting t as 50 minutes . But the answer is 45 minutes. Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: most likely just confusion about **which** time is asked for - the time the first two pipes are open, or the time the third one is? Former is 50 min, latter is 45 min.

Comment: The total time from start was asked.

Comment: no, that would be 50. Your work is perfectly correct. Sometimes the confusion is in the textbook/exam/author/etc. But people often don't pay close attention to the exact wording of questions, so I had to ask.

Comment: @NickPavlov Ok, thanks !